# Static resource not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have created a simple `spring-boot` application and the folder structure for resources looks like this:

[image]

This is data in application.properties file:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/**
server.port=8089
```

In `studentsList.jsp` I try to use javascript function defined in `studentFunctions.js`, but in browser console I get the following error:

```
error: "Not Found"
message: "No message available"
path: "/static/js/studentFunctions.js"
status: 404
timestamp: "2018-12-06T16:53:02.777+0000"
```

I have seen several similiar questions but I haven't found solution yet.

[image]

I tried both `spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/static/**` and `src/main/resources/resources` and in both cases error is:

[image]

Comment: how did you tried to include your js file in jsp?

Comment: The folder structure looks alright - this is also the default, i think. Did you try to remove the static path pattern line from the `application.properties` and see if Spring just finds your stuff? Also, try removing the `/` from the beginning of the path to your js file (if you have any).

Comment: I removed `spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/**`, but same happens

Comment: `src/main/resources` is copied into the classpath root; you would need to put your files into `src/main/resources/resources`.

Comment: @chrylis, I will try it now

Comment: Did you tried this: `spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/static/**`

Comment: Without using any properties in my spring-boot, I was able to expose the static directory as if they were from the root server, so in your case `localhost:8089/js/studentFunctions.js`. You could try using `../js/studentFunctions.js` through your subdomain and see if that is resolved.

Comment: `http://localhost:8089/resources/static/js/studentFunctions.js` is wrong. it should change to this: `http://localhost:8089/static/js/studentFunctions.js`

Comment: Problem is solved. I needed to remove `spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/**` and also to change `src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/studentFunctions.js"` to `src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/studentFunctions.js"` Intellisence did a bad job for me in second case.